# Could not find or load main class error in command line

Tags: java, input, io, console, output

I can't run java programs in command line.
This is my screenshot:
[image]

`IOConsoleDemo.class` is in the same directory, I don't know why this error is occurring.

Comment: go to your project root directory and run `java com.input.IOConsoleDemo`. The package name is part of the class name

Comment: Yeah! it worked. Thank you very much!